# How to train the Shared Layers in PyTorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation

I have the follow code

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchviz import make_dot, make_dot_from_trace

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input, output):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(input, output)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x

model = Net(12, 12)
print(model)

x = torch.rand(1, 12)
y = model(x)
make_dot(y, params = dict(model.named_parameters()))
```

Here I reuse the `self.fc` twice in the `forward`.

The computational graph is look

[image]

I am confused about the computational graph and,
I am curious how to train this model in back propagation? It seem for me the gradient will live in a loop forever. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no issues with your graph. You can train it the same way as any other feed-forward model.

1. **Regarding looping:** Since it is a directed acyclic graph, the are no actual loops (check out the arrow directions).
2. **Regarding backprop:** Let’s consider `fc.bias` parameter. Since you are reusing the same layer two times, the bias has two outgoing arrows (used in two places of your net). During backpropagation stage the direction is reversed: bias will get gradients from two places, and these gradients will add up.
3. **Regarding the graph:** An FC layer can be represented as this: `Addmm(bias, x, T(weight)`, where `T` is transposing and `Addmm` is matrix multiplication plus adding a vector. So, you can see how data (`weight`, `bias`) is passed into functions (`Addmm`, `T`)

- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.addmm.html
- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.t.html